# Why UITableViewController's view do not have the UITableViewController as the Referencing Outlet?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I drag a `UITableViewController` to an XIB

If I click on the `UITableViewController` I see that it has a view property.

However if I click on the `UITableView` in there I saw that it has no referencing outlet

[image]

Comment: So what's the problem? The TableViewController knows on which view it should work on, in this case the tableview. There need not be an outlet in the tableview.

Comment: You have to implement your own Outlet… (like everytime ?)

Comment: Well, I want the tableViewController subclass to be the delegate for another tableView. Basically I have a tableView that may have 3 delegates.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll right click on the `UITableViewController` you'll see that there is an outlet called `view`. You don't need a separate reference to the tableView inside the `UITableViewController`. The tableView knows it's a part of the `UITableViewController`, you don't need an outlet for it. `UITableViewController` is not the same as `UITableView` and acts differently. In my experience I've found that `UITableViewController` is a lot more restrictive without any real benefits over a regular `UIViewController` and a `UITableView` in it.